# Django-Ajax : Form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I have a problem with a form submission :

My script JS :

```
function submit_form(){
    var form = $("#theform").serializeArray();
    var the_players = document.getElementsByName("theplayers");
    var tab_players = [];
    for(variable of the_players){
        var name = variable.id.split("_")[1];
        tab_players.push(variable.value);
        }

    // *** I send a tab and THE FORM ***
   $.post("/myview_players",{"theplayers[]": tab_players,"form[]":form}).done(function(data){window.location.reload();}); 

   return false;
}
```

And the view (url : 'myview_players') :

```
...
if request.method == "POST":    
    requete = request.POST
    if requete.is_ajax() :
        form = playersForm(requete.get("form"))

        if form.is_valid() :
            print("Valid ! ")
        else :
            print("Not valid...")
        ...
```

I pass in argument to the playersForm juste a form sent by Ajax.
In the terminal, the message "Not valid" is showed... **Why ?**

Comment: Django forms relies on actual whole `POST` object, so putting into it one field won't work. Especially if that field is an string. Maybe with dict it will work. Check what type you're getting from `requete.get('form')`.

Comment: so requete.get('form') return None but requete.getlist('form[]') return : [u'[object Object]', u'[object Object]', u'[object Object]']) !    and requet.get('form[]') return  u'[object Object]' ... I understand nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Change requete to request in your view. Spellcheck?

Also, in $.post, if you pass as "form[]":form, the view would expect a list.
Try doing "form":form

Answer (score 0):

After many research, I find a solution :

```
form_data = parse_qs(request.POST['form'].encode('ASCII')) 
query = QueryDict(request.POST['form'])
form = playersForm(query)
```

That works when I do : form.cleaned_data['name_of_field']

**What do you think ?
Is it a good solution ?**